# Append defs tag and use it within SVG in D3.js

Tags: javascript, html, svg, d3.js

I am grouping 3 circles together within `defs` tags so they can be seen in an `SVG`. I have been also been recommended to use the `use` tag so I can see this shape that is defined within `defs` and recreate it anywhere within the `SVG`. I am creating them and appending them to data using `D3.js`. However, My problem is when I use the `use` tag, it seems to me that I am creating a new SVG every time I want to display the shape that is in the `defs` tag. My questions are: Is there anyway to use the `defs` tag without using the `use` tag? The second question is: How can I display that shape within the `defs` tag many times within only one `SVG` without creating an `SVG` every time. Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="US-ASCII">
</head>
<body>
<div id ="mainSVG">
<svg id = "packSVG" width = "1160" height = "620" style = "outline: thin solid black" 
version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<defs>
<symbol id= "mySymbol">
    <circle cx="200" cy="70" r="25" fill="red" />
    <circle cx="170" cy="80" r="20" fill="red" />
    <circle cx="230" cy="80" r="20" fill="red" />
    </symbol>       
</defs>
</svg>
</div>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var dataset = [20, 60, 90, 120];
var display = d3.select("body").select("#mainSVG").select("#packSVG").selectAll("use")
  .data(dataset).enter().append("use")
  .attr("xlink:href","#MySymbol")
  .attr("transform", function (i) { i+=50; return "translate(" + i + "," + i + ")";});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Could anyone please help with this issue? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: What makes you think you are creating a new SVG every time ?

Comment: When I check the inspector in Firefox and mouseover the created shapes, it shows me as follows: use 1160x620.

Comment: What are you seeing in the DOM ?

Comment: I see the shapes in the DOM.

Comment: I have a feeling semantics are getting in the way when you mention SVG. Do you simply mean you are creating a new element every time (in which case I get it, or a specific SVG tag each time (so you have lots of nested SVGs). There are ways to reference defs without a use, for example as a fill attribute pointing to the id, but I don't think that would help here. is there a specific problem you actually trying to resolve ? I think you will end up with new elements whatever, so I'm not sure of a cleaner way than you are doing.

Comment: I would like to reference defs without a use. When I append defs to the data in d3.js, I do not see the shapes. When I append use to the data, I see the shapes. May you please help me how to reference defs without use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can define the circle group using  using g element as shown below and there is no need for creating multiple svg. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ls5vt88x/)

HTML

```
<svg id="mainSVG" width="600" height="500">
   <defs>
    <g id="mySymbol">
        <circle cx="200" cy="70" r="25" fill="red" />
        <circle cx="170" cy="80" r="20" fill="red" />
        <circle cx="230" cy="80" r="20" fill="red" />
    </g>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

Javascript code

```
var dataset = [20, 60, 90, 120];

var display = d3.select("body")
   .select("#mainSVG")
   .selectAll("use")
   .data(dataset)
   .enter()
   .append("use")
   .attr("xlink:href","#mySymbol")
   .attr("transform", function (i) { i+=50; return "translate(" + i + "," + i + ")";});
```

Note that there typo in your code. The id `mySymbol` is misspelled as `MySymbol` while creating use elements.

Comment: Thank you very much. It is very much appreciated. May you please briefly explain to me where my problem was in my previous code? Once again, thank you so much for your assistance.

Comment: The one and only problem in your code was the typo. You misspelled the id of symbol definition while setting xlink:href attribute.